# Python 3.7 ArgumentParser.add_subparsers require positional before optionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to create a python script that will execute another script, depending on the first positional parameter. Think along the lines of how `git add` behaves.

Problem is that ArgumentParser appears to want the positional sub-command to be listed... at the end. Which is pretty counter-intuitive. (When you want to list all files, you do `ls -a [FILE positional]`, not `-a ls [FILE positional]`, so why would it require `scriptname [optionals] subcommand` instead of `scriptname subcommand [optionals]` since 'subcommand' is the 'real' command?)

Toy example:

```
def get_arg_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    #  set up subprocessors
    subparser = parser.add_subparsers(required=True)

    parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_const', const=True, default=False, help="Enable verbose output.")

    subcommand1_subparser = subparser.add_parser('subcommand1')
    subcommand1_subparser.add_argument('--foo1', type=float)

    subcommand2_subparser = subparser.add_parser('subcommand2')
    subcommand2_subparser.add_argument('--foo2', type=float)

    return parser


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        get_arg_parser().parse_args()
        # more
    else:
        get_arg_parser().print_help()
```

Problem is that if I try to run `python toyexample.py subcommand1 --verbose`, it complains about `error: unrecognized arguments: --verbose`. Meanwhile, `python toyexample.py --verbose subcommand1` works, but it's requiring the optionals *before* the name of the command you're actually intending to run.

How do I override this?

Comment: You defined '--verbose' as an argument for the `parser`.  Once `parser` encounters 'subcommand1', parsing is passed to `subcommand1_subparser`.  It's that subparser that complains about unrecognized arguments.  The main parser does not resume parsing after the subparser is done.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me arrive at a solution!

Comment: @bramvanroy: that was entirely the point. Reread what I wrote more carefully: I said that's *not* how you use LS, so of course it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @hpaulj, I found a solution: simply add the shared arguments to both subparsers.

I put the `parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_const', const=True, default=False, help="Enable verbose output.")` line in a `add_shared_args_to_parser` to function, which I then call twice, passing the subparsers.

Net result is that the subparsers have some unfortunate (but not terrible) duplication and the main parser has nothing but subparsers.